# Node.js API express web server MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm writing an Node.js REST API using express web server and mongoDB as DB server.
The project's directory tree is the following :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFWGt.png

When I try to access "/new/test" route, I'm getting the error "Cannot GET /new/test". By accessing this path it should create an new entry into the DB based on "firstname" URL parameter.

Routes.js :

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app) {
  var americaine = require('../controllers/americaineController');

  // Firstname Routes  
  app.route('/new/:firstname')
    .post(americaine.new_firstname);   


};
```

DB entry creation function is located on Controller.js :

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),

  Firstname = mongoose.model('Firstname');

  exports.new_firstname = function(req, res) {
    var new_firstname = Firstname(req.params.firstname);
    new_firstname.save(function(err, firstname) {
      if (err)
        res.send(err);
      res.json(firstname);
    });
  };
```

Model.js :

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var FirstNameSchema = new Schema({
  /*id: {
      type: Number,
      required: false
  },*/
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Firstname', FirstNameSchema);
```

Do you guys have any ideas about my issue ? Thanks in advance.

Jérémy

Comment: You cannot GET it because it's defined as POST `app.route('/new/:firstname').post(americaine.new_firstname)`

Comment: '/new/:firstname' route takse one parameter used for DB entry creation. According to [REST API standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), data providing requires POST delivery function.

Answer (score 0):

change the method .post() to .get()

since you're actually doing a get request and not a post request.

Comment: You really should not GET to "create" something. So let's just consider this an error in the "request" rather than the method.

Comment: Why we should not do it?

Comment: Because of the [REST standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) of course. GET is not a "creation" verb. It means to "retrieve" something. To "create" things you would use POST or PUT depending on the actual underlying action.

Comment: I also thought about REST API standards. '/new/:firstname' route takes one parameter forwarded for new DB entry creation. So according to REST API standards, delievery POST function should be used for data providing.